# Show the toast or alert or popup view only once in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have one sample app. The application contain toast when I login the screen going to home page view load toast appear perfectly my problem is the toast show only once at homepage again comes to the homepage toast does not needed? But when I login again I need to show the toast. How can I do this. Any one give the solution.

The toast is declared on `viewDidLoad`:

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];
NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
if(status == NotReachable)
{
    NSLog(@"No Internet.");
}

else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi)
{
    wifiImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"wifi_green.png"];
    [self.view makeToast:@"Wifi Is Connected" duration:3.0 position:CSToastPositionBottom];
}

else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN)
{
    ethernetImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"ethernet_green.png"];
    [self.view makeToast:@"Ethernet Is Connected" duration:3.0 position:CSToastPositionBottom];
}
```

Comment: use `NSUserDefualts` to check whether toast shown.

Comment: But when I login again I need to show the toast

Comment: so easy during logout clear the flag from `NSUserDefualts `

Comment: Do reset flag at didfinishlaunching method in appdelegate.m file

Comment: see my updated answer @MUNNA

Comment: Great it's works thank you so much  Mind_Sparkles & Vinodh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store toast shown status as BOOL value in your `NSUserDefaults`. Check the value of that variable before showing the popup.

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"ToastShown"] == FALSE)
 {
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"ToastShown"];
     // add your code
}
```

During Logout  Or in `didfinishlaunching`

```
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:FALSE forKey:@"ToastShown"];
```

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; Is this not required?

Comment: @MUNNA - no need

Comment: Okey. Thank you @Vinodh

Comment: synchronize() is automatically invoked at periodic intervals but you can use synchronize in special conditions.See apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize).

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485109/is-it-mandatory-to-call-nsuserdefaults-synchronize-method

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by saving your login state to NSUserDefaults. You can achieve same by using following steps.

1. Save bool to indicate user has logged in or not

   ```
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:FALSE forKey:@"LoggedIn"];
   ```
2. Check whether user has logged in previously or login first time and display toast accordingly.

   ```
   if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"LoggedIn"] == FALSE)
   {
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"LoggedIn"];
     //show toast
   }
   else
   {
    //hide code for previously logged in user
   }
   ```
3. Clear NSUserDefault value or you can even reset it to false on logout.

   ```
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:FALSE forKey:@"LoggedIn"];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

use this three line simple code

```
  if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"toast"] == FALSE)
 {
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"toast"];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
  //Toast code will go here...
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

try using main thread to toggle user interaction of UIButton after 3 seconds that actions to show Toast.